# show polygon area only in bing map

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I have polygon rectangle shape in bing map.. how can modify the code so only the area inside the polygon is showing...

here is the code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function GetMap()
            {
                // Initialize the map
                var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),{credentials:"At7RkDItXU6kncQzZa8M9lFfMbzPgmulJYLkhYn5JMMZfHL86lNyFZvGWWngxaAP",
                                                 });

                // Create a polygon
                var vertices = new Array(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(20,-20), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(20,20), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-20,20), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-20,-20), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(20,-20));
                var polygoncolor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,100,0,100);
                var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(vertices,{fillColor: polygoncolor, strokeColor: polygoncolor});

                // Add the polygon to the map
                map.entities.push(polygon);
            }

            </script>
        </head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be considered as a mask on the control.

**Masking with inverted polygon**

The technique consists in creating a polygon out of the current bounding box and that will exclude the specific area.

Of course, this approach has its limitations and one would be that it will be hard to manage multiple advanced shape in this case.

This has been explained by our fellow Alastair in this blog post and would be easily adapted so everything would run on the client side only with a global polygon and a 'hole' while using advanced shape module:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/masking-out-particular-areas-of-interest-on-bing-maps/

[image: Bing Maps masking polygon by Alastair]

**Self overlapping polygon**
One other solution would be to create a polygon on the current bounding box to draw a global polygon on top of all the visible area and then you add locations so the polygon loops only where you have your own area.

By default, the fusion mode would result in an exclusion that will hide both polygons, you can have a look at a useful property in SVG but it could also has its limits depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to remove the border. If that is the case set the strokeThickness to 0 and don't borth setting the strokeColor

Comment: I mean the area around the rectangle shape cannot be seen.